# search in lucene index

Tags: java, lucene

I created a lucene(3.0.1) index on a column to search with in text, On testing on this text :

```
$GLD is a great example of why it does not make sense EVER to try and catch a falling knife.
```

It gives me result if I search by keyword `"falling"` but I am getting nothing on searching by `"$GLD"`

I am using standardAnalyzer :

```
String longString = "$GLD is a great example of why it does not make sense EVER to try and catch a falling knife."

Analyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_30);
doc.add(new Field("data", longString, Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED));
```

Because `Field.Index.ANALYZED` is set it should create tokens and `$GLD` should be present. Analyzer will remove stop words from the text, is word `$GLD` is also getting removed in the process.

Comment: Are you specifying the same `Analyzer` when creating your `QueryParser`?  "$GLD" is likely transformed (I believe into "gld"), and if different Analyzers, or different versions, are used when indexing and in the QueryParser, then end results of analysis may not agree.

Comment: I am not defining `QueryParser` and `Analyzer` in searching query, I am using  `IndexSearcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(directory);
`, `TermRangeQuery` and  `TermQuery`. But it was able to search by gld, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Your document's field is changed by Analyzer.  Why don't you use Analyzer on your query before you search. Meanwhile a QueryParser would help a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You should check the `StandardAnalyzer`, the `StandardAnalyzer` may remove `$` and may use `LowerCaseFilter` in its procedure (I'm not sure, I just know 2.3 and 4.1). The `LowerCaseFilter` will make the words to lower case. When you search upper case letter, you won't get any thing.

You can use Luke to check the tokenized result in index.

Answer (score 0):

It also helps to use [Luke](http://code.google.com/p/luke/) to check that your query does what you think it does.